# How to debug react native app without internet?

Tags: react-native

As far as I know, build `React Native` projects have to boot up `Node server`.

I want to create `offline mode` with my app.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if you want to run an app offline, it can be resolved through settings. But if you want to debug, there are currently no modules that have been developed for offline debugging.

[The link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging) are currently available for debugging. But you have to have an Internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know I can run my app with release mode to test offline mode. But I just want to know debug in offline environment is possible or not.

Thanks again.